# Openshift time-out error (configure timeout client)

Tags: openshift, haproxy

I have an app hosted on Openshift. We have a funtionality that let the user upload file onto $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, then a nodeJS funtion is called to insert into our DB. In case of big tables this operation may take 5-7 minutes to be completed.

BUT, before the server complete the operation the client side got disconected and a  **Gateway Time-out  error** appears at 120000ms, the server side process continue the operation, and after sometime is completed, but the client side goes with this horrible error.

I need to know where I can edit those 120000ms. I edited the haproxy with different values but timeout is still 120s. Is there another file somewhere?

```
retries                 6
timeout http-request    8m
timeout queue           8m
timeout connect         8m
timeout client          8m
timeout server          8m
timeout http-keep-alive 8m
```

found 2 haproxy files:

- haproxy/conf/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
- haproxy/versions/1.4/configuration/haproxy.cfg

both are edited

I guess there is multiple timeouts out there, but need to know where they are, or how to change client-side timeout

The app Gears: 3

```
haproxy-1.4 (Web Load Balancer)
 Gears: Located with nodejs-0.10
nodejs-0.10 (Node.js 0.10)
postgresql-9.2 (PostgreSQL 9.2)
   Gears:          1 small
smarterclayton-redis-2.6 (Redis)
```

Answer (score 1):

5-7 minutes is an awfully long time for a web request.  It sounds like this would be the perfect opportunity for you to explore using background tasks.  Try uploading your data from the client and processing it in the background with something similar to delayed_job in rails.